# K8s: StatefulSet how to increase time between resatrt of pod in case fails

Tags: kubernetes, application-restart, statefulset

I have integration test, where i start StatefulSet, wait untill ready and then do some asserts.

My problem that if Application fails - it try to restart too fast.
And I can't get logs from failed pod.

SO my question how can i increase time between Restart of pod in StatefulSet?
Because K8s controllers do not support RestartPolicy: Never.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to view the logs of the terminated pod, you can do

`kubectl log <pod_name> --previous`

Answer (score 1):

I would try to run the service in question as a regular deployment and convert it to a StatefulSet after I analyze the issue with the application.

Why can't you get the logs from the terminated pods?

Maybe you should try to set terminationGracePeriodSeconds on the SS container to make the dying pods stay longer for analysis.

Comment: Because every time when pod, recreated it ahs same id and name.

Comment: `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` is 1800, but if pod die by error. it's day fast any way.